# angular routerlink multiple parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My path to the component is something like `module1/module2/module3`.

Inside this component I have childRoutes with parameters: `:id/:subId`.

```
<a  routerLink="12" >go to detail</a>
```

If the user clicks `go to detail` link twice page redirecs to `module1/module2/module3/id1/id1`

The second parameter should come from the subId component. If user clicks the routerLink inside id component it should redirect to `module1/module2/module3/id1`. If user clicks the routerLink inside subId  it should redirect to `module1/module2/module3/id1/id1`

routerLink inside subId :

```
<a  routerLink="12" >go to sub detail</a>
```

Router is like :

```
{
   path: 'module1',
   component: module1Component,
   children: [
       {
          path: 'module2',
          component: module2Component,
          children: [
                {
                   path: 'module3',
                   component: module3Component,
                   children: [
                        {
                            path: '',
                            component: MonitoringComponent,
                        },
                        {
                           path: ':id1', 
                           component: id1Component,
                           children: [
                              { 
                                 path: ':id2', 
                                 component: id2Component
                              }
                           ]
                         }
                    ]
                } 
          ]
       } 
   ]
}
```

Comment: can you show a little bit more of code or explain what is your problem, please?

Comment: How are your routes defined? Try defining routes in every module for the components that are declared in just that modules. All children routes will be in children modules.

Comment: Edited, added route json